# Updated to Android .3.7 Now Configuration Messed Up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I was using a .2.x version of Android Studio. Just installed to .3.7 and got two obvious error messages... "Android SDK is not configured for module 'FormerlyWorkingProject' or corrupted" and (when I try to look at any layouts I get) "Rendering Problems- No render target selected."  I tried downgrading to .3.2, but no luck.

It seems that some part of my configuration is now missing or messed up. Will someone please give me some guidance on this?

Thank you so much!

Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your **Project Structure** dialog, choose **Android SDK** under **Platform Settings**. Make sure it has the path to the right JDK and Android SDK. Correct them, close your project, and reopen.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. Works like a charm now. Thanks again.